# Get Current Cell Value in EditingControlShowing

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, textchanged, backcolor

What I'm trying to do is, if I type "red" into a cell, then the cell's backcolor changes to red and if I type "blue" into a cell, then the cell's backcolor changes to blue. The problem I'm getting is, if I type "blue", only "blu" is recorded as mystring, as the textchanged event records the cell value before the change, so the cell's backcolor never changes color as a result. I hoping someone might have an idea on how to get the current cell value after a textchange. My current code below (this is just an example). Any ideas or help will be appreciated, thanks.

```
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
    Me.DataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
End Sub

Dim EditingControl As DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl

Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing

    EditingControl = e.Control
    AddHandler EditingControl.TextChanged, AddressOf EditingControl_TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub EditingControl_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    mystring = Me.DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value
    If mystring = "red" Then
        EditingControl.BackColor = Color.Red
    ElseIf mystring = "blue" Then
        EditingControl.BackColor = Color.Blue
    Else
        EditingControl.BackColor = Color.White
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to use the CellEndEdit event.  That is not going to give you instant feedback but that's what it takes to tame DGV.  You can make a Timer work, if you really want to, but ah, that's hokey.

Comment: Thanks Hans for your reply, I have been using cellendedit, but I didn't like how the backcolor would change on leaving the cell. I'm mainly going to be using the code to color the cell red if something has been entered incorrectly.

Comment: Well, you don't know when the user is done typing until he moves to another cell.  Slapping him with "you're doing it wrong!" *while* he's typing isn't very friendly, is it?  You can use CellValidating to prevent him from leaving a bad value in the cell.

Comment: Yeah, I might do that, go back to backcolor change on cellendedit. Thanks for your replies.